# Android google ads error (null reference ?)

Tags: java, android, admob, adview

I am actually stuck in this error for the last 24h and still can't find solution
the error description:

> 11-06 18:53:37.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1698): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)'
>   on a null object reference

this is some of the xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_pattern"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
.
.
.
.
.
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_05"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


</LinearLayout>
```

oncreate method in mainActivity.java :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView adview = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        // Request for Ads
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

                // Add a test device to show Test Ads
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("")
                .build();

        adview.loadAd(adRequest);
        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(mainActivity.this);
        // Insert the Ad Unit ID
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(AppConstants.Interstitial_Id);

        // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
.....
```

i can't see any error in this i checked all imports libraries everything is ok
Please help me I'm running out of time :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is failing because it is not finding an element with id `adView` in your layout.

Make sure the XML file you displayed above is actually `activity_main.xml`.

And do a clean build.

Comment: i restarted the whole eclipse but no fix then i saw ur answer and i just clean and it work now thank you!

Answer (score 1):

in XML replace this

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

instead of

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced Similar issue. When i checked closely in resourse file There were two resourse file for my activity:

\res\layout\activity_main_lauch.xml

\res\layout-v21\activity_main_lauch.xml

I was modifing single file, hence it was throwing error. 
when i apply the change in both files it started working.
Hope it might help.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put this into your com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView and in your LinearLayout :

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

EDIT: 
You need to pull ID number of your test device from LogCat. Just use the AdManager method and set it to TEST_EMULATOR like the logcat says. If you run on an actual device with usb debugging and watch the logcat, the ID will appear in there.

Comment: Have you put right permissions in your Manifest file?

Comment: Why do you call: this.findViewById?

Comment: Remove that   from your constructor.